# How to disable <a onclick> when the user holds control

Tags: javascript, html, templates

Usually, when people click on a link, I have onclick bound to it. And then return false.

When people click with "control", they expect a new page to open up. Therefore, I want to ignore the onclick AND/OR detect it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `event` object has a "ctrlKey" boolean flag, so you can check that in your handler. It depends a little on your framework, but generally if your handler returns `false` then you'll have "defeated" the click.

In IE, the `event` object is a global (that is, a property of the "window" object). In other browsers, it's a parameter passed to the handler. A common idiom therefore is:

```
function clickHandler(theEvent) {
  theEvent = theEvent || window.event;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Aka first line of `onclick` function: `if (event.ctrlKey) return true;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `OnMouseDown` event.

Answer (score 0):

You may hook the OnKeyPress event and check if the control key is being pressed. If so, raise a flag that is used on the OnClick. If the flag is up, then skip all the OnClik normal code and put, on the else do what you need.